# Op-amp - Converting a negative ramp to a positive ramp

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I have an analog input that I need to measure. The analog input is single-ended and ranges from -10V to +10V.

I want to try and measure that output with an ADC, which has a 0-3.3 V range.

I want -10 V to be 0 V, +10 V to be 2.5 V, and 0 V to be 1.25 V.

Right now, I have -10 V = 5 V, 0 V = 2.5 V, 10 V = 0 V (I can handle just a simple voltage divider to halve the range)

This is the circuit I have now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6qefT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I figure that there's some difference amplifier circuit I can use, but my knowledge of these analog circuits is lacking.

On the board, I have spare op-amps, as well as a 1.25 V reference to use.

[Here](http://tinyurl.com/27ogq7ck) is an easily editable simulation of the circuit.

Comment: The manufacturer of your opamps has application notes like [Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sloa097) or [Non-Inverting Op Amp with Non-Inverting Positive Reference Voltage Circuit](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sboa263).

Comment: Does the input signal have a significant impedance or are you already using one of the spare op-amps as a buffer?

Answer (score 4):

This resistor divider gets you close:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUQQe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A sweep of V1 from −10V to +10V outputs 0V to +2.22V:

[image]

If you want the full 0V to +2.5V, you'll need some gain \$A\$:

$$ A = \frac{2.5}{2.22} = 1.125 $$

In this next design, the op-amp is configured as a non-inverting amplifier with gain 1.125. The overall response to inputs from −10V to +10V is an output going from 0V to +2.5V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSusV3.png)</sup>

Sadly, that would require a negative supply for the op-amp, because it cannot get all the way to 0V output without one. If you want to use 0V for the negative supply, you'll have to sacrifice a few tens of millivolts at the bottom end.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fALBss.png)</sup>

Note that I've increased R2 slightly, to raise the minimum potential at X to a little over 0V. Since this also increases maximum potential there, I've also had to reduce gain a little. For inputs between -10V and +10V, this last design will output +30mV to +2.5V:

[image]

Comment: +1 for showing that some things can be done just using resistors (almost).

Answer (score 3):

As per RusselH's suggestion below, here's the improved version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS1e7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The output is no longer reversed, but follows the input, except scaled & shifted from -10V ... +10V to 0V ... +2.5V (roughly).

### Original Answer below

If you can live with the ramp being reversed, so -10V gets translated into +2.5V and +10V gets translated into 0V, then you can do it with a single opamp.
You could easily reverse it back again in your MCU's code.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnK6N8.png)</sup>

The inverting gain of 0.12 isn't perfect, but it gets you to within about 50mV at each end.

The output offset is set by Vref, scaled by R1 & R2, and multiplied by the non-inverting gain: \$1 + \frac{R3}{R4}\$

so:
\$(\frac{Vref . R1}{R1 + R2}).(1  + \frac{R3}{R4})\$

= \$(\frac{1.25 . 10k}{10k + 1.2k}).(1 + \frac{1.2k}{10k})\$

= \$(1.116) . (1.12)\$

= 1.25V

Comment: This is a differential amplifier. Lift R1 from ground. Connect to V1+. Lift R4 from V1+. Connect to ground. Then the polarity is correct.

Comment: @RussellH thx for the hint - updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with reducing the gain using a simple potential divider like this: -

[image]

- negative 10 volts in maps to -1.25 volts out
- positive 10 volts in maps to +1.25 volts out

[image]

So, all you have to do is add an offset like this: -

[image]

And, you get what you want.

Of course this task is made easier by using a standard voltage reference such as +2.5 volts and attenuating it to +1.42857 then adding an op-amp buffer before connecting it to R1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that uses only two standard values of resistors and your present op-amps.

Note the need for a negative supply for the op-amps, however -5V is adequate. The worst-case output voltage of U1 is -1.25V at +10V input. With your idea of buffering it first, you'd need something like -12V to handle a -10V input. If you don't have a negative rail, you could use something like a 7660 charge pump to generate it from +5V.

[image]